# Lower voice transmit threshold for Xbox Live

Tags: xbox-360

Whenever I am in a party on Xbox live my friends ask me why I haven't said anything in so long. However I'm typically yacking away - unknowingly to myself. I have a stock Xbox mic, I've taken the foam off the end of it. I have a feeling there are two things that impact this:

1. I have a deep voice
2. I don't shout into the mic

If I raise my voice to a personally uncomfortable level then people can hear me again. Is there any way to lower the transmit threshold so I don't have to shout or put the mic down my throat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your description, it sounds like they can hear you sometimes, but not others, so most of the [Xbox support options](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-live/troubleshoot/chat-communication/troubleshooting-parties-voice-chat) won't apply.

Unfortunately, there really aren't any settings that can be changed for outbound chat. You can just make sure you are unmuted, and that your microphone is in an optimal location. You'll have to test this with someone else to see when they can hear you best by moving your microphone around.

I suppose it's possible you could have a flaky microphone, but I'm not going to go out and tell you to drop money on a new cheap one, or a more expensive one, as that may not fix the problem. You could always check a stores return policy and try out one of the Bluetooth or other manufacturer microphone options.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I didn't think there were any settings but I just wanted to be sure. Have you ever seen wireless mics work better than wired ones?

Comment: @jocull I've never tried a wireless mic. Not sure.